# which OSI layer handles?

Tags: networking

some file transfer is in progress. the connection break s and then 
later after some time is restored. then on the file transfer continues 
from the point where it left off, which OSI layer handles this?
presentation, application, TCP, IP, Sesssion

Answer (score 1):

First of all, TCP/IP is not OSI (see [here)](http://www.cellsoft.de/telecom/tcpiposi.htm). And if the connection really breaks, TCP won't be able to allow for continuation of transfer, it has to be done at a higher level (which is not defined in the TCP stack).

Answer (score 1):

You are using FTP client which works at application layer.When any connection is created a session is maintained as per the capabilities of the application.Session management is done at session layer.So when FTP is able to resume the transfer that is because of session layer. OSI model is only a reference model  and each layer has different set of protocols. To have more in-depth understanding of the flow in OSI model layers i have created an example. You can refer to this link to understand more.
https://thinkingmonster.wordpress.com/2016/08/20/understanding-osi/

Answer (score 0):

> which OSI layer handles this

The OSI session layer would handle it, if you were using OSI layers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, layers are always referred as per OSI model, no matter wether its actually being used as specific stack. I totally agree with @thinkingmonster's answers. To add more on this I would say its the Transport layer ( layer4 PDU as per the OSI ref model) and layer 2 in TCP/IP stack.

This is typically handled by Error recovery mechanism using Sequence and Acknowledgement field in TCP header.TCP achieves reliability in both directions, using the Sequence Number field of one direction combined with the Acknowledgment field in the opposite direction.

[image]

This is just a little overview to have an idea, you might want to refer the Doc to have full handshake cycle with client and server.